# Javascript Promises Chaining Multiple Errors

Tags: javascript, chaining

How come that all my Resolved Callbacks are properly executed but only 
1 Error Callback is being run ?

In the example here if `longOperation(true)` I get only one error, while when run with false I get the two resolved messages. In my understanding each `.then` returns a new promise which is in the error state for the second `.then` error callback registration

This example is written using Typescript !

```js
function longOperation(error) {
  return new Promise < any > ((resolve, reject) => {
    if (error) {
      reject("Error")
    } else {
      setTimeout(function() {
        resolve(true)
      }, 1000)
    }

  })
}

let op = longOperation(true);

op
  .then(result => {
    console.log("Resolved #1")
  }, undefined)
  .then(result => {
    console.log("Resolved #2")
  }, undefined)
  .then(undefined, error => {
    console.log("Error1")
  })
  .then(undefined, error => {
    console.log("Error2")
  })
```

Comment: Are you using TypeScript or Flow by any chance? Because `Promise<any>` is not valid JavaScript by itself, so your example won't run as it is.

Comment: I don't fully understand the example, but a couple things that may help. Here is the method  for `Promise.prototype.then(onFulfilled, onRejected)`. The first param is the success callback, while the second callback is for the fail/rejected. You are just continually chaining together `.then` with a success callback, but no error callback. Also you have the option of using `Promise.prototype.catch(onRejected)` instead of passing second error callback to `.then`

Comment: Yes indeed, Typescript. Edited post accordingly

Comment: The error handling function will be invoked on error. so, if in your first error handling function you don't invoke an error, the second one will not be called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Promises can "recover".

The error will propagate down the chain of ".then"s until it finds an error callback. When it does it will execute the error callback and pass the return value down to the next promise's resolve method.

So only the next closest error callback to the promise will get executed.

If you want to catch all possible errors along the chain just put your error callback at the end of the chain and all errors will be handled by it.

In your code example you are actually creating 5 promises. The original one and 1 for each ".then". The 2nd and 3rd only have an onResolved method and the last two only have and onRejected method.

This is how it will be executed:

1st Promise(op): I just rejected. I see I have a deferred promise with no onRejected callback. So I'll just call it's reject method with the same value I rejected with.

2nd Promise: The previous promise called my reject method and I also have a deferred promise with no onRejected callback. So I'll just call it's reject method with the same value I rejected with.

3rd Promise: The previous promise called my reject method. I have a deferred promise too, but mine does have an onRejected callback. I,ll call the callback with the value I rejected with, and I'll call my deferred promise's resolve method with the callback's return value.

4th Promise: The previous promise called my resolve method. I have a deferred promise, but it doesn't have an onResolved callback so I'll just call it's resolved method with the value I resolved with.

5th Promise: The previous promise called my resolve method. I resolved and did nothing more because I have no deferred promise.

Answer (score 2):

The first error handler catches the error, just like a regular `catch` block. If you want the chained promise to be rejected, you have to rethrow the error:

```js
Promise.reject().then(() => {
  console.log(1);
}).then(() => {
  console.log(2);
}).then(null, e => {
  console.log(3);
  throw e; // <= rethrow here
}).then(null, e => {
  console.log(4);
});
```